# Facebook OpenGraph movie.rates not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to get the Facebook OpenGraph movie.rates action type working but with zero success so far and hoping someone with experience of this could point me in the correct direction.

Basically I want to share a users movie review on their timeline. I've been messing around with the code below, it creates the dialog box but does not post to timeline.

I've tried adding rating values, rating scales, played around with multiple object types but just can't get it.

my Code:

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "video")
            .putString("og:title", "some movie name")
            .putString("og:description", "test")
            .putString("og:image", imageUrl)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("video.rates")
            .putObject("video", object)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("video")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    shareDialog.show(this, content);
```

Comment: Check your activity log - if it shows up there, everything went fine. Not everything gets shown on timeline.

Comment: Checked activity log and nothing there. The callback returns a 0 (should be -1) with error message Unknown Error (very helpful!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK got this working with the below code. This will start a video.rates open-graph dialog as required:

```
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
            .putString("og:type", "video.other")
            .putString("og:title", titleText)
            .putString("og:image", imageUrl)
            .putString("og:description", "Some description")
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("video.rates")
            .putDouble("rating:value", 5.0f)
            .putInt("rating:scale", 10)
            .putString("review_text", reviewText)
            .putObject("other", object)
            .build();

    ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("other")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();

    ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    shareDialog.show(this, content);
```